# How to fix Calibre Author amalgamations?

Tags: calibre

Somehow I have managed to have several 'authors' that are an amalgamation of different names. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get them split up to how they are supposed to be.

When I browse the Authors, it will just have a couple of entries like:

> David Mack, Keith R. A. Decandido
>
> David Mack, Marco Palmieri, Dayton Ward, Kevin Dilmore

listed under the D, whereas I obviously expect the former to be two separate authors, and four authors for the latter.

I have tried removing second author completely from the books that had the former author, but the moment I re-add them it becomes its own unique category yet again. I have tried this through grid editing and the individual metadata screen with no result.

How do I convince Calibre to treat these authors right?

Note that I use the default author split settings, which should be capable of splitting those author strings just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma (`,`) can be part of the name  (e.g. in names having the suffix `, Jr`), but also when they are in reverse order: `Mack, David`.
So you cannot use that to separate names and because of the second use, if a comma is already there the name doesn't get split and reordered, as Calibre thinks that has already been done.

I use the word `and` between names, but IIRC you can also use the ampersand (`&`), to separate the names:

```
 David Mack and Marco Palmieri and Dayton Ward and Kevin Dilmore
```

If you put that in Calibre's `Authors` field and click the right arrow next to it the resulting `Author sort` field will be:

```
Mack, David & Palmieri, Marco & Ward, Dayton & Dilmore, Kevin
```

and your book will be under `M`